# Error when trying to add simple filter to Kendo Grid in React Component

Tags: typescript, filter, kendo-grid

I was having issues adding a filter to my kendo grid, So to troubleshoot I went to

[Kendo React Filtering Documentation/Examples[1](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/filtering/)

I copied both the main.jsx, and sample-products.jsx code verbatim from the first example "filter rows" into an app on my local host but I am still getting the same error. I can not complile main.jsx in vscode that is copied directly from the documentation. I know the code "works" because you can click "open in stackblitz" in the link and it works perfectly.

Here is main.jsx (copied from the documentation) and the error below.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Grid, GridColumn as Column } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
import { filterBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { sampleProducts } from '../data/sample-products.jsx';

class PositionsPanel extends React.Component {
    state = {
        filter: {
            logic: "and",
            filters: [
                { field: "ProductName", operator: "contains", value: "Chef" }
            ]
        }
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <Grid
                style={{ height: '420px' }}
                data={filterBy(sampleProducts, this.state.filter)}
                filterable
                filter={this.state.filter}
                onFilterChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({
                        filter: e.filter
                    });
                }}
            >
                <Column field="ProductID" title="ID" filterable={false} width="60px" />
                <Column field="ProductName" title="Product Name" />
                <Column field="FirstOrderedOn" width="240px" filter="date" format="{0:d}" />
                <Column field="UnitPrice" width="180px" filter="numeric" format="{0:c}" />
                <Column field="Discontinued" width="190px" filter="boolean" />
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}

export default PositionsPanel
```

[image: Error Image]

Do you know what could cause the identical code to compile/work in Stackblitz, but not in vscode? Maybe I have an outdated package I am not sure? thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

the error came from the fact that my local file was typescript .jsx. The version that worked in the documentation was .js . As soon as I saved the file as JS it worked perfectly.